# R Shiny on Ubuntu Server: User is not able to open a folder in a Windows Platform

Tags: r, operating-system, shiny

I was running R Shiny app on Windows and everything was fine. But now that i'm running the code in a Ubuntu Server, the user can not open the folder.

Code to open the folder:

```
opendir <- function(dir) {
    if (.Platform['OS.type'] == "windows"){
      shell.exec(dir)
    } else {
      system(paste(Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER"), dir))
    }
  }
```

Maybe the problem occurs because the script is reading the server OS (instead of the user) and is not executing shell_exec.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:

The right way to do this is using html in R but this only works in IE. Example:

```
tags$a(href=file://C:/My Computer")
```